# sending mail in languages other than English

Tags: python, django, email, utf-8, multilingual

I need to send mail not in English (Chinese, Japanese, etc.). 
I have a template.py file from where i get subject and body.
template.py

```
      #!/us/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                       
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   
  subject = '附录E: 配置参考'
  body = '附录E: 配置参考'
```

I read the body and subject from template.py file.

```
  msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from, to)
  msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
  msg.send()
```

It's work fine for English but not for other language. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you generating `html_content`?

Comment: Is there an errer message? I see the problem rather in missing incoding of the header values, which is not as easy as just running ``.encode("utf-8")`` on a unicode string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885062/unicodeencodeerror-with-attach-file-on-emailmessage-django-error?noredirect=1#comment22664718_15885062

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the page to unicode

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The charset recognises multiple languages and their respective characters.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
from email import Charset
# Due to http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11212
Charset.add_charset('utf-8',Charset.SHORTEST,None,'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

As Burhan asked, how do you generate `html_content` and in which mail client did you check the mail? Normally `html_content` should be valid HTML having the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
 in its `<head>` as David suggests.

Also, check the `django.conf.settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET`, if it's not `'utf-8'`, you could either set it to `'utf-8'` or set the `msg.encoding = 'utf-8'` in your code. (If you want to use charset such as `gb18030`, replace `'utf-8'` with it)

Plus, in Python 2.X code, better to always use unicode for string containing non-ascii characters, thus

```
subject = u'附录E: 配置参考'
body = u'附录E: 配置参考'

# instead of
subject = '附录E: 配置参考'
body = '附录E: 配置参考'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try so

```
import sys
reload(sys)  # to enable 'setdefaultencoding' again  (optional)
sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
```

subject.encode("UTF-8")