# UnicodeEncodeError with attach_file on EmailMessage Django error

Tags: python, django

So I get this error when I try to send an email with EmailMessage in Django.

UnicodeEncodeError at /checkout/

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 15:
```

The body of the message contains some unicode character that breaks the script.

The thing is that everything works just fine if I omit the attachment OR if the body doesn't contain any unicode characters. The subject can contain unicode characters with no unicode error. So it happens only in combination with unicode characters in the body and the attached file. This seems like a bug to me.

The attachemnt is a generated pdf file.

The code running on Ubuntu 10.04, apache2, mod_wsgi, python 2.6.5, Django 1.5

The code I am using is

```
t = loader.get_template('orders/invoice_email.html')
c = {
    'order': order,
}

email = EmailMessage(subject, t.render(Context(c)), from_mail, [to, ])
email.encoding = "utf-8"
email.content_subtype = "html"
email.attach_file(invoice.name)
email.send()
```

and the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in     get_response
115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/projects/vitamei-shop/modules/orders/views.py" in checkout
48.             order = form.save()            
File "/var/www/projects/vitamei-shop/modules/orders/forms.py" in save
71.         email_invoice(order)
File "/var/www/projects/vitamei-shop/vitamei/.././modules/orders/views.py" in email_invoice
320.     email.send()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
255.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
95.                 sent = self._send(message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in _send
113.                     force_bytes(message.as_string(), charset))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in as_string
169.         g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in flatten
84.         self._write(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in _write
109.             self._dispatch(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in _dispatch
135.         meth(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in _handle_multipart
201.             g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in flatten
84.         self._write(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in _write
109.             self._dispatch(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in _dispatch
135.         meth(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/email/generator.py" in _handle_text
178.         self._fp.write(payload)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /checkout/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: could you isolate the code where the error occurs? then we could try to work around. The full code is hard for me to execute myself.

Comment: are you trying with the same file everytime?

Comment: @User I don't know how to isolate it more. The error happens when the script tries to send the email.

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo the attached pdf is a generated invoice, and yes I have tried it with different files, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Is there a traceback that you can show?

Comment: @catherine I already have that in all of my files

Comment: @user I have added the traceback to the main question

Comment: if there is any `unicode` string that appears on your side of the code, can you try to `.encode('utf8')` it?

Comment: to only .encode('utf8') didn't do the trick for me, it was one of the first things that I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after trying and trying I found a solution that worked for me.

```
t = loader.get_template('orders/invoice_email.html')
c = {
        'order': order,
    }

body = u''.join(t.render(Context(c))).encode('utf-8').strip()
email = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_mail, [to, ])
email.encoding = "utf-8"
email.content_subtype = "html"
email.attach_file(invoice.name, mimetype="application/pdf")
email.send()
```

I hope this will help if someone has the same problem.